# Snakemake with integrated conda env not properly installed

Tags: python, conda, snakemake, virtual-environment

I have a rule in my snakemake pipeline to run multiqc :

```
    rule summaryReport:
        input:
            fastqc_forward = expand(final_path + "/fastqc/{sample}_R1_fastqc.html", sample = samples),
            fastqc_rev = expand(final_path + "/fastqc/{sample}_R2_fastqc.html", sample = samples)
        output:
            report = final_path + "/fastqc/report_quality_control.html"
        params:
            path = final_path + "/fastqc"
        conda:
            "multiqc.yaml"
        shell:
            "multiqc {params.path} --filename {output.report}"
```

with the conda env file multiqc.yaml :

```
name: multiqc 
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - bioconda
dependencies:
  - multiqc=1.12
```

When I run the pipeline I've got the following error :

```
Activating conda environment: /XXXX/.snakemake/conda/e8f3e6def45259d12dddd42fcd679657
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/XXXX/.snakemake/conda/e8f3e6def45259d12dddd42fcd679657/bin/multiqc", line 6, in <module>
    from multiqc.__main__ import multiqc
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'multiqc'
```

I've tested to activate the conda environment manually and indeed there is the same error when running multiqc.

I've tested to create a conda env thanks to "multiqc.yaml" outside snakemake, and in this case multiqc is running correctly.

If someone has an idea about this it would help me a lot!

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely want to install python as well, since according to [docs](https://multiqc.info/docs/) it's not recommended to use the system-wide python:

```yaml
name: multiqc 
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - bioconda
dependencies:
  - python=3.7
  - multiqc=1.12
```

Comment: It works fine with python installation, thank you very much !

Comment: That's great, glad it works!